# Query builder gives exception

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I am using query builder like

```
$querym =$querym->select('DISTINCT(a.id)') ->where ('a.doctorid =:u')
                                                              ->setParameter('u', $u);

$query =$query->select('DISTINCT(d.id),d.name,d.dob,d.mobile')

                                                    ->innerJoin('d.PatientSymptoms','ps')
                                                    ->innerJoin('ps.symptoms', 's')

                                                    ->andWhere('ps.symptoms =:name')
                                                    ->where($query->expr()->In('d.id', $querym))
                                                    ->setParameter('name', $name);
```

gives me
    `Error: Method Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__toString() must not throw an exception`

Is it possible to write it some another way?
pls help me.

Comment: if i have to guess, your $querym is an arrayCollection.  you should probably change that to be an array.   $querym->toArray()

Comment: it gives Attempted to call method "toArray" on class "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder".

Comment: oh, my bad. i didn't see you had querym as a query builder.  you should probably have it execute that query before passing it into the second query

Comment: can you pls elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the getDql() method (but i think it fail when the subquery have a parameter) :

```
$querym = $querym->select('DISTINCT(a.id)') ->where ('a.doctorid =' . (int) $u);

$query = $query->select('DISTINCT(d.id),d.name,d.dob,d.mobile')->...->where($query->expr()->In('d.id', $querym->getDql()));
```

You can also use 2 queries (as Derick F say), something like that :

```
$ids = array();
$querym = $querym->select('DISTINCT(a.id)') ->where ('a.doctorid = :u')->setParameter('u',$u);
$as = $querym->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
foreach ($as as $a) $ids[] = $a[1];

$query = $query->select('DISTINCT(d.id),d.name,d.dob,d.mobile')->...->where("d.in (:ids)")->setParameter('ids',$ids);
```

Comment: second option has typo where("d.id in (:ids)")